# Anyone tried SwitchPreference introduced in ICS?

Tags: android

I noticed Google have introduced [`SwitchPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html) in API 14
Anyone tried it out yet, how it looks, functions etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks VERY similar to the one in iOS :), nice addition though.

BTW, the [`Switch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) is a proper UI widget, not just a preference.

> A Switch is a two-state toggle switch widget that can select between
>   two options. The user may drag the "thumb" back and forth to choose
>   the selected option, or simply tap to toggle as if it were a checkbox.
>   The text property controls the text displayed in the label for the
>   switch, whereas the off and on text controls the text on the thumb.
>   Similarly, the textAppearance and the related setTypeface() methods
>   control the typeface and style of label text, whereas the
>   switchTextAppearance and the related seSwitchTypeface() methods
>   control that of the thumb.

[image]

Comment: The widget was used internally in Honeycomb -- you can see it in the control area that expands when you tap on the time in the lower-right corner, where the `Switch` is used for toggling on/off airplane mode and such.

Comment: Great thanks, does look like it's lifted straight from ios. Looks from the api that you can configure the text display for the on/off states, could be really nice alternative to two items in a `ListPreference`

Comment: @Rob previous to 4.0 this was done using a check box rather than two items in a list. Which is the case you are referring to?

Comment: No that's not quite what I meant, I was talking about instances where you want to give a user an option that isn't a yes/no as far as they are concerned. Doesn't matter anyhow. Thanks for info.